# schemaOptions for embedded models (typegoose)

Tags: node.js, typescript, mongoose

What I do normally in mongoose is:

```
import { Schema, model } from 'mongoose';

const SubCategorySchema = new Schema({
    value: {
        type: String
    }
})

const CategorySchema = new Schema({
    value: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    subCategories: [SubCategorySchema]
});

SubCategorySchema.set('toJSON', {
    virtuals: true,
    versionKey: false,
    transform: (doc, ret, options) =>
    {
        delete ret._id;
        return ret;
    }
})

CategorySchema.set('toJSON', {
    virtuals: true,
    versionKey: false,
    transform: (doc, ret, options) =>
    {
        delete ret._id;
        return ret;
    }
});

export const Category = model('Category', CategorySchema);
```

When the data comes through express and into my web app. The application prints the `id` rather than the `_id` for both `CategorySchema` and `SubCategorySchema` which is what I want. However, I can't seem to replicate this on **typegoose**. I can only manage to do it for `Category` by doing this:

```
import { Typegoose, prop, arrayProp } from 'typegoose';

import { ICategory, ISubCategory } from './category.interface';

export class SubCategory implements ISubCategory
{
    readonly id: string;

    @prop({ required: true })
    public value: string;
}

export class Category extends Typegoose implements ICategory
{
    readonly id: string;

    @prop({ required: true })
    public value: string;

    @arrayProp({ items: SubCategory })
    public subCategories?: SubCategory[];
}

export const CategoryContext = new Category().getModelForClass(Category, {
    schemaOptions: {
        toJSON: {
            virtuals: true,
            versionKey: false,
            transform: (doc, ret, options) => {
                delete ret._id;
                return ret;
            }
        }
    }
});
```

I've even tried doing:

- `new SubCategory().getModelForClass(SubCategory, {...})`
- `new SubCategory().setModelForClass(SubCategory, {...})`

but to no avail.

---

for the first example, i would get this result:

```
[
    {
        id: 'asdjuo1j2091230',
        value: 'A Category',
        subCategories: [
            {
                id: 'asdl;ka;lskdjas',
                value: 'A SubCategory'
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

And for the second example, I would get this result:

```
[
    {
        id: 'asdjuo1j2091230',
        value: 'A Category',
        subCategories: [
            {
                _id: 'asdl;ka;lskdjas', //<----- want it to be id, but it's displaying as _id
                value: 'A SubCategory'
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

Is this feature not implemented or have i missed it out from the docs? What other alternatives are there for this?

Answer (score 0):

For usable fixes, particularly for `Typegoose v.10.0` and `Mongoose v.6.8` users. It could resemble this one, for example.

In models directory.

```js
import * as mongoose from 'mongoose'
import { prop, getModelForClass, modelOptions } from '@typegoose/typegoose'
import { Base } from '@typegoose/typegoose/lib/defaultClasses'

// extend Base in order to define _id and id
export interface ICommon extends Base {
   value: string
}

// delete or rename _id to id in modelOptions using virtual property
@modelOptions({
  schemaOptions: {
    timestamps: true,
    versionKey: false,
    toJSON: {
      virtuals: true,
      transform: (_doc, ret) => {
        ret.id = ret._id.toString()
        delete ret._id
      },
    },
  },
})

export class SubCategory implements ICommon {
  _id!: mongoose.Types.ObjectId

  id!: string
  
  @prop({ required: true })
  public value!: string
  
  //...
  
}

export class Category implements ICommon {
  _id!: mongoose.Types.ObjectId

  id!: string
  
  @prop({ required: true })
  public value!: string
  
  @prop() 
  public subCategories?: [SubCategory] // if an array of subdocuments is preferred
  
  // or an array of references if you'd rather just pick one format
  @prop({ ref: () => SubCategory }) 
  public subCategories?: Ref<SubCategory>[]
  
  // ...
  
}

export const SubCategoryModel = getModelForClass(SubCategory)

export const CategoryModel = getModelForClass(Category)
```

Populate the reference data somewhere on the controllers or services directory.

```js
import { Request, Response } from 'express'
import { CategoryModel, Category } from '../models'

// ....

const allCategories = async (_req: Request, res: Response) => {
  const categories: Category[] = await CategoryModel.find({}).populate('subCategories', { __v: 0 })
  if (!categories) throw Error('Problem fetching category list!')
  return res.status(200).json(categories)
}

// ....

export default {
 allCategories,
  // ....
}
```

END. Plug the function/s into the routes and start checking the endpoint. Now, `_id` is virtually gone, replaced by `id` in the server or if you make a request to the client, but of course, not in the DB.

Happy coding!